# Unfirom convergence of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n(x)\}$ be sequence of functions defined on a set $E$. Let for any $n$ we have $|f_n(x)|\leqslant c_n$ and $c_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Does it follow that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $E$?

I can't prove it rigorously.

Comment: What is $x$?  Is $x$ fixed before choosing $n$?
If you have $||f_n(x)||_E \le c_n$, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @GNUSupporter, It means that you fix $n$ and for any $x\in E$ we have $|f_n(x)|\le c_n$. Can you show the proof please?

Comment: This standard result is from the definition of sup-norm.

Comment: Maybe it's standard but I can't prove it. I would be very grateful to you for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Counterexample is the following:

Let $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $E=[0,1)$. For any fixed $n$ we see that $|f_n(x)|=x^n<1=c_n$ and $c_n\to 1\neq 0$ but $\{f_n(x)\}$ does not coverges uniformly on $E$.

Comment: the OP has asked for a proof ;not counter example

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

By the given hypothesis if $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ then $f(x)=0$.

So $M_n=\sup_{x\in E} |f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in E} |f_n(x)|\leq c_n\to 0$ for $n\to \infty $

Thus $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$

Comment: Very nice result! What about if $c_n\to L$ as $n\to \infty$ and $L\neq 0$?

Comment: then the answer is no

Comment: Can you show a countereexample?

Comment: Well you can consider $f_n(x)=x^n;x\in[0,1] $ Here $c_n=1$ .$f_n$ does not converge uniformly